# iphone uiswitch not displaying on/off

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator, uiswitch

I recently updated xcode to 4.2 and my iphone 3gs that I use for testing to iOS5.  Since then all the uiswitches no longer show on/off.  instead they display i/o.  this is only on the iphone.  on the simulator they appear correct.  any idea what is causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same problem for iOS5 in the simulator and the device.

I added the "Localization native development region" key to my info.plist file and it fixed the problem.

Comment: yes, on the phone with apple support they said this shouldn't be necessary but it did fix the problem.

Comment: same here, and adding the settigng to info.plist fixed it. i note that new Xcode projects now have this set by default:

Comment: <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
 <string>en</string>

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is localization-related - did you by any chance change the system language on your 3GS recently?